# Any suggestion for improving listening skills in Japanese? Any recommended YouTube channels?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if you have any awesome channels you can recommend. I have been wanting to improve my listening comprehension and it's been difficult :(

Comment: I'm also fine with JLPT-specific listening materials, but I'd appreciate if it's something that has practical or entertainment value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting website. I've used it a tiny bit, and found it useful enough to bookmark. Among many other tools, it announces the news at a slow speed, and then then using the exact same words at a native speed:
https://newsinslowjapanese.com/

And, there is other study material there, some for the JLPT. I think an (intro / basic) account is free. Thanks for reminding me about it!

Of course, there are podcasts of Japanese news. One is called "Round Up World Now" on Nikkei Radio.

Comment: oh that, it's been a while since I checked that site. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is quite what you are looking for, but I have found it useful.

[Youglish for Japanese](https://youglish.com/japanese)

This site searches through the subtitles of Youtube videos for whatever word or phrase you enter. Very useful for finding out how people actually say something. It starts the video a few seconds before the searched phrase, and I also like that it has a button to return to that spot. It seems to have more false hits than the English version because a lot of Chinese and Korean videos have Japanese subtitles, but it's still useful.

Comment: That's interesting! I'll go check that out.

Comment: Just tried it and I'm blown away! I wonder what the algorithm is like.