# YouTube channels for listening

Tags: discussion, resources

I was looking for YouTube channels to improve my listening, but at the moment I'm not really finding anything.

I found [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/any-suggestion-for-improving-listening-skills-in-japanese-any-recommended-youtu) and [this](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/any-suggestion-for-improving-listening-skills-in-japanese-any-recommended-youtu) discussions, which have interesting material, but not channels, so since that question is over a year old I was wondering if someone could have some suggestions; maybe something about Japan culture and tradition, but really anything goes, also if it'd be great if it had Japanese subtitles, to be able to check what I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine recommended watching  ゲーム実況 channels for listening practice. So far I've only listened to [レトルト](https://www.youtube.com/user/retokani) and [キヨ](https://www.youtube.com/user/KIYOisGOD) but I can see how this is going to be useful since they read the in-game text with different styles and emotion, aside from their normal chatting and ツッコミ。